# SQL - Select the same column, twice

Tags: sql, database-design, select

I don't know if it is correct, but look the following schema:

[image]

An Entity can be either a Carrier or a Customer. Every customer must be associated with a Carrier, this Carrier can be the own Customer.

I'm stuck, tried without success to perform a single query that returns the **NAME** of the customer and the **NAME** of his Carrier. Is there a way to make such operation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `entity` twice and give the `name` column aliases.  Remove the last join if additional `carrier` fields are not needed.

```
select customer_entity.name as customer_name, customer.credit, -- additional customer fields...
        carrier_entity.name as carrier_name, carrier.carrier_stuff -- additional carrier fields...
        from entity as customer_entity
        inner join customer on (customer.id_entity = customer_entity.id_entity)
        inner join entity as carrier_entity on (customer.id_carrier = carrier_entity.id_entity)
        inner join carrier on (carrier.id_entity = carrier_entity.id_entity)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am interpreting id_carrier as being the entity id for carrier:

```
select ec.name as CustomerName, eca.name as CarrierName
from customer c join
     entity ec
     on c.id_entity = e.id_entity join
     entity eca
     on c.id_carrier = eca.id_entity
```

This eliminates the need to join back to the carrier table, unless you need additional information from there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join twice against the `entity` table, once for each type. Use their aliases (`ca, cu` below) to reference each in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT
  /* Carrier info */
  ca.id_entity AS carrier_id_entity,
  ca.name AS carrier_name,
  ca.date AS carrier_date,
  carrier.carrier_stuff,
  /* Customer info */
  cu.id_entity_as AS customer_id_entity,
  cu.name AS customer_name,
  cu.date AS customer_date,
  customer.discount,
  customer.payment
FROM
  carrier 
  JOIN customer ON customer.carrier_id =  carrier.id_entity
  /* JOIN first against entity for carrier */
  JOIN entity ca ON carrier.id_entity = ca.id_entity
  /* and again between customer and entity */
  JOIN entity cu ON customer.id_entity = cu.id_entity
```